# Can't create an app with Ionic 3 running "ionic start"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m not able to create a new app with Ionic 3.20.1
Once I’ve chosen the template the console hangs and nothing else happens. Only an empty folder is created. BUT It’s going well with Ionic 4.

I also tried to run `ionic start myApp blank` and it loaded something into the folder BUT it stopped again after the next choosing step.

Could please anyone help me with this issue? I really need to use Ionic 3, but how to fix this?

**Ionic** 3.20.1
**Cordova** 8.1.2
**Node.js** 10.14.2

Thank you!

[The console look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HccQb.png)
Upd: ionic info --verbose output:

```
[DEBUG] Reason for not using local CLI: BASE_DIRECTORY_NOT_FOUND
[DEBUG] CLI flags: { interactive: true, confirm: false }
[DEBUG] { cwd: 'D:\\...', local: false, binPath:
        'C:\\...\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath:
        'C:\\...\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\dist\\index.js' }
[WARN] You are not in an Ionic project directory. Project context may be missing.

cli packages: (C:\...\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1

System:

    Node : v10.14.2
    npm  : 6.5.0
    OS   : Windows 10

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: The first time you setup a project and specified 'blank' as the type of project. The second time you did not.. So it is asking which kind you want 'tabs'.  You then hit enter to continue. If there is more like errors being output by command post the whole thing. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start/

Comment: I DID hit enter - that's when it hangs. Updated the post to be more clear

Comment: Do you not see a load of text start to appear as it does stuff after hitting enter for tabs? If you do - take a screenshot of that, or better copy/paste the tail end of it. If it's hanging - you aren't out of disk space or something weird like that are you?

Comment: No, I do not. THe console was open for like an hour and nothing else appeared. Only what you can see on the screenshot was there. As I said, it's going well with Ionic 4. Tried also with ionic 3.9.2 - didn't work.
There's also enough disk space.

Comment: Are you on a Windows or Mac environment? I would be doing a few checks to make sure node, and ionic are correctly installed. Try running `ionic info --verbose.` Paste that output back into question. Also when you are creating this new ionic project, you aren't still in the project folder of the old project are you? i.e. you should be one level up.. So projects co-exist in same parent..

Comment: FYI: I stayed on 3.19.0 - there were some issues with ios-deploy on the newer ones - if you upgraded to OS/X Mojave. You would not normally hit that issue until you were preparing a build to create an IPA, or load it into the AppStore.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfp6s.png - This is what I have for example.

Comment: Win10 as you can see. Didn't really get the folder part but did try to create in different directories.

Comment: FYI. I was also running that in a created app folder - so some of the things like the @ionic/appscripts line appeared in mine. You might not have that if the start did not complete correctly and you weren't in the project folder.

Comment: I would start Googling a bit more. To me it looks like you are missing cordova. It may be absent in newer Ionic version - haven't gone past 3 myself yet. But I feel sure you need it for ionic 3

Comment: So I've downgraded to 3.19.0. Now it first asks about the update and then does nothing. So I went to the existing empty (due to the issue) project and ran the --verbose and then it stops again after asking about the update. 
I did install it today again, it's 8.1.2.  Googling didnt really help :\

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM2Bc.png - This comes from here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8d25mmdPm0 `npm install -g cordova` (I had 8.0.0 will post how to install specific version in a sec)

Comment: `npm install -g cordova@8.0.0` (since you already have ionic) This is the extra bit you need - the screenshot from the video did both at once (ionic and cordova)

Comment: Unfortunately I could not see Ionic 3 install guide. There may be some way to get a URL for that, perhaps someone on slack or another SO user can add that..

Comment: Daily It may keep prompting you to update CLI. Just say no each time.

Comment: I do have cordova already and to be sure installed the 8.0.0 now but the issue is still there. It gets frozen right after choosing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was node.js. I had to downgrade it v10->v8 and now it's working.